# Using ScreenManager in Kivy (Python) with several .py screens

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I've recently started using the Kivy framework to create an app with multiple screens that I would like to merge, so that, for example, pressing a button on the login screen opens another page. I've been trying to use the ScreenManager library for days but I can't get it to work, there are several tutorials on the internet but everyone uses different variations. Below I attach the code of the login page where, by pressing the "Log in" button, the second screen should open.

login.py:

```
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Window.size = (350, 580)

kv = """
MDFloatLayout:
    md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    Image:
        source: "img\\logo5.png"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .85}
        size_hint: .18, .18
    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint: .9, .07
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .68}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos:self.pos
                radius: [4]
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 217/255, 217/255, 217/255, 1
            Line:
                width: 1.1
                rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 4, 4, 4, 4, 100
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Phone number, username or e-mail"
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            height: self.minimum_height
            background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
            font_size: "14sp"
            font_name: "MRoboto"
            hint_text_color: 170/255, 170/255, 170/255, 1
            padding: 13
            cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint: .9, .07
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .59}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos:self.pos
                radius: [4]
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 217/255, 217/255, 217/255, 1
            Line:
                width: 1.1
                rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 4, 4, 4, 4, 100
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Password"
            size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            height: self.minimum_height
            background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
            font_size: "14sp"
            font_name: "MRoboto"
            password: "true"
            hint_text_color: 170/255, 170/255, 170/255, 1
            padding: 13
            cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    Button:
        text: "Log in"
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        size_hint: .9, .07
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .43}
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        font_size: "13sp"
        font_name: "BRoboto"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 98/255, 170/255, 243/255, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                radius: [4]
    MDLabel:
        text: "Don't have an account?"
        color: 172/255, 172/255, 172/255, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .74, "center_y": .095}
        font_size: "13sp"
        font_name: "MRoboto"
    MDTextButton:
        text: "Sign up"
        color: 98/255, 170/255, 243/255, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .685, "center_y": .095}
        font_size: "13sp"
        font_name: "MRoboto"
    MDCheckbox:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "48dp", "48dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_x": .1}
        on_active: app.show_password(*args)
    MDLabel:
        id: password_text
        text: "Show Password"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_x": .43}
"""
class Login(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def show_password(self, checkbox, value):
        if value:
            self.root.ids.password.password = False
            self.root.ids.password_text.text = "Hide Password"
        else:
            self.root.ids.password.password = True
            self.root.ids.password_text.text = "Show Password"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="BRoboto", fn_regular="font\\Roboto-Bold.ttf")
    LabelBase.register(name="MRoboto", fn_regular="font\\Roboto-Medium.ttf")
    Login().run()
```

list.py:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, ILeftBody
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

Window.size = (350, 580)

kv = """
<ListItemWithCheckbox@OneLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    MyAvatar:
        source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png"
    MyCheckbox:

<Lists@BoxLayout>
    name: "lists"
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTopAppBar:
        title:"Hide the story to:"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        elevation: 3

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)

class MyCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass

class MyAvatar(ILeftBody, Image):
    pass

class Users(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Liste"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        list = Factory.Lists()
        for i in range(30):
            list.ids.scroll.add_widget(Factory.ListItemWithCheckbox(text="Item %d" % i))
        self.root = list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Users().run()
```

In my tests I tried to instantiate the ScreenManager both in the login.py code and in a third new file created from scratch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To start with, this code needs to be within a single app.  There isn't a reason to create two separate main functions.

Comment: Hi Mark, first of all thank you for your reply. Since I'm still gaining experience, to create these two screens I mainly relied on two online tutorials and then I modified the code according to my needs. It turns out that I've created two files that actually represent two different apps. How should I go about making an "all in one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code, so everything is in login.py. It is using the screen manager to switch between screens.
You could also put the list class in a list.py file and move the imports it uses to that file.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd import app
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, ILeftBody
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

Window.size = (350, 580)

kv = """
WindowManager:
    id: manager
    LoginScreen:
        id: login_screen
    ListScreen:
        id: list_screen

<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login_screen'
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Image:
            source: "img_logo5.png"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .85}
            size_hint: .18, .18
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: .9, .07
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .68}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos:self.pos
                    radius: [4]
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 217/255, 217/255, 217/255, 1
                Line:
                    width: 1.1
                    rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 4, 4, 4, 4, 100
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Phone number, username or e-mail"
                size_hint: 1, None
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                height: self.minimum_height
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                font_size: "14sp"
                # font_name: "MRoboto"
                hint_text_color: 170/255, 170/255, 170/255, 1
                padding: 13
                cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: .9, .07
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .59}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 250/255, 250/255, 250/255, 1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos:self.pos
                    radius: [4]
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 217/255, 217/255, 217/255, 1
                Line:
                    width: 1.1
                    rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 4, 4, 4, 4, 100
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Password"
                size_hint: 1, None
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                height: self.minimum_height
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                font_size: "14sp"
                # font_name: "MRoboto"
                password: "true"
                hint_text_color: 170/255, 170/255, 170/255, 1
                padding: 13
                cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Button:
            text: "Log in"
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            size_hint: .9, .07
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .43}
            background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
            font_size: "13sp"
            # font_name: "BRoboto"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 98/255, 170/255, 243/255, 1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4]
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'list_screen'
        MDLabel:
            text: "Don't have an account?"
            color: 172/255, 172/255, 172/255, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .74, "center_y": .095}
            font_size: "13sp"
            # font_name: "MRoboto"
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Sign up"
            color: 98/255, 170/255, 243/255, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .685, "center_y": .095}
            font_size: "13sp"
            # font_name: "MRoboto"
        MDCheckbox:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "48dp", "48dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_x": .1}
            on_active: app.show_password(*args)
        MDLabel:
            id: password_text
            text: "Show Password"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_x": .43}
            
<ListItemWithCheckbox@OneLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    MyAvatar:
        source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png"
    MyCheckbox:
    
<ListScreen>
    name: 'list_screen'
    BoxLayout
        name: "lists"
        orientation: "vertical"
    
        MDTopAppBar:
            title:"Hide the story to:"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            elevation: 3
    
        ScrollView:
    
            MDList:
                id: scroll
"""


class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    """ Window Manager """
    pass


class ListItemWithCheckbox:
    pass


class LoginScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class Login(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def show_password(self, checkbox, value):
        if value:
            self.root.ids.password.password = False
            self.root.ids.password_text.text = "Hide Password"
        else:
            self.root.ids.password.password = True
            self.root.ids.password_text.text = "Show Password"


class MyCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass


class MyAvatar(ILeftBody, Image):
    pass


class ListItemWithCheckbox:
    pass


class ListScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self):
        app.title = "Liste"
        # my_list = Factory.Lists()
        for i in range(30):
            self.ids.scroll.add_widget(Factory.ListItemWithCheckbox(text="Item %d" % i))
        # self.root = list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Login().run()
```

First I create the WindowManager using the kv language.

```
WindowManager:
    id: manager
    LoginScreen:
        id: login_screen
    ListScreen:
        id: list_screen
```

Then I create each screen uning the format : followed by the name: 'screen_name' so I can reference it later.

```
<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login_screen'
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Image:
    ...
<ListScreen>
    name: 'list_screen'
    BoxLayout
    ...
```

In the Button definition in the kv language I use:

```
on_release: root.manager.current = 'list_screen'
```

The root part tells it to look in the current screen for the manager and set the current screen to 'list_screen'

The ListItemWithCheckbox@OneLineAvatarIconListItem: in the kv language, tell it to create a custom widget based on the OneLineAvatarIconListItem widget and set some options every time it is used.

In the Python part, I define the matching custom widgets and the matching WindowManager class.

```
class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    """ Window Manager """
    pass

class ListItemWithCheckbox:
    pass

class MyCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass

class MyAvatar(ILeftBody, Image):
    pass

class ListItemWithCheckbox:
    pass

class LoginScreen(MDScreen):
    pass
```

Then I define the 2 screens.

```
class LoginScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class ListScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self):
        app.title = "Liste"
        # my_list = Factory.Lists()
        for i in range(30):
           self.ids.scroll.add_widget(Factory.ListItemWithCheckbox(text="Item %d" % i))
```

The LoginScreen does not need any code in it so I just pass.
The ListScreen uses the on_enter method which is run after the screen is fully drawn to set the window title and draw the checkboxes.

Hopefully I got all the explanations correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to edit the code, I have tested it and it works as I intended. Can you just summarize for me the steps you took by modifying or adding pieces of code? So that I know how to handle also other screens. Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include explanations of what I was doing at each part.

Comment: Perfect, I saw that in the on_enter method you modified the code, but by copying the original one from the build method the program doesn't compile (I also tried with other screens). AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Comment: The build method gets executed before the screen is drawn, and on_enter gets executed after the screen is drawn.  AttributeError: 'NoneType' happens because you are trying to access a variable before it has been defined.  Which variable is giving you the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Long story short, I just copied the code from my file's build method to yours' on_enter method. But now it doesn't matter to find the cause of this error, I just want to understand how I can use the methods you commented or deleted in the on_enter function (eg self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"). Who knows if I will ever be able to finish this neverending story, hahahah

Comment: I updated my answer to include the theme settings.  It should be placed in the __init__ method of the MDApp class. ie. class Login(MDApp):  The __init__ method runs before the build method.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you Kivy screens basics. Below it's an example app with 3 screens. Each screen contain buttons:

- to go to specified screen by name
- to go to next definied screen
- to go to previous definied screen
- to call method definied in current screen
- to call method definied in other screen
- to call method definied in screen manager
- to call method definied in app

On top of `screenssample.kv` file there is a screens hierarchy. Class `MyScreens` is a screen manager, parent of three screens: `MyScreen1`, `MyScreen2`, `MyScreen3`.
To go to another screen you have to assign it's screen name to manager's current attribute `manager.current`.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

# hierarhy:
#   ScreensSample (App)
#   |- MyScreens (ScreenManager)
#      |- MyScreen1 (Screen)
#      |- MyScreen2 (Screen)
#      |- MyScreen3 (Screen)

class MyScreens(ScreenManager):
    def screen_manager_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen manager')

class MyScreen1(Screen):
    def screen_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen 1')

class MyScreen2(Screen):
    def screen_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen 2')

class MyScreen3(Screen):
    def screen_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen 3')

class ScreensSample(App):
    def app_method(self):
        print('Hello from app')

ScreensSample().run()
```

screenssample.kv

```
MyScreens:
    MyScreen1:
    MyScreen2:
    MyScreen3:

<MyScreen1>:
    name: 'screen_one'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: f'I am {root.name}'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to screen 2'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to next screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to previous screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
        Button:
            text: 'This screen method'
            on_release: root.screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Other screen method (from screen 2)'
            on_release: root.manager.get_screen('screen_two').screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Screen manager method'
            on_release: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
        Button:
            text: 'App method'
            on_release: app.app_method()

<MyScreen2>:
    name: 'screen_two'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: f'I am {root.name}'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to screen 3'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to next screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to previous screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
        Button:
            text: 'This screen method'
            on_release: root.screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Other screen method (from screen 1)'
            on_release: root.manager.get_screen('screen_one').screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Screen manager method'
            on_release: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
        Button:
            text: 'App method'
            on_release: app.app_method()

<MyScreen3>:
    name: 'screen_three'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: f'I am {root.name}'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to screen 1'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen_one'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to next screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to previous screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
        Button:
            text: 'This screen method'
            on_release: root.screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Other screen method (from screen 1)'
            on_release: root.manager.get_screen('screen_one').screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Screen manager method'
            on_release: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
        Button:
            text: 'App method'
            on_release: app.app_method()
```

I hope this sample is easy to understand. But even based on this simple py and kv file you may notice that having all screens within one kv file and all screen classes within one py file will produce huge files hard to develop and maintain.

Below is same example but every screen is definied within its separate kv and py files. I think it makes code more readable, easier to develop/maintain.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
import screen1, screen2, screen3

# hierarhy:
#   ScreensSample (App)
#   |- MyScreens (ScreenManager)
#      |- MyScreen1 (Screen)
#      |- MyScreen2 (Screen)
#      |- MyScreen3 (Screen)

class MyScreens(ScreenManager):
    def screen_manager_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen manager')

class ScreensSample(App):
    def app_method(self):
        print('Hello from app')

ScreensSample().run()
```

screenssample.kv

```
#:include screen1.kv
#:include screen2.kv
#:include screen3.kv

MyScreens:
    MyScreen1:
    MyScreen2:
    MyScreen3:
```

screen1.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MyScreen1(Screen):
    def screen_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen 1')
        # self.manager.get_screen('screen_two').screen_method()  # sample how to call other screen method from here
        # self.manager.screen_manager_method()  # sample how to call screen manager method from here
        # App.get_running_app().app_method()  # sample hot to call app method from here
```

screen1.kv

```
<MyScreen1>:
    name: 'screen_one'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: f'I am {root.name}'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to screen 2'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to next screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to previous screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
        Button:
            text: 'This screen method'
            on_release: root.screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Other screen method (from screen 2)'
            on_release: root.manager.get_screen('screen_two').screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Screen manager method'
            on_release: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
        Button:
            text: 'App method'
            on_release: app.app_method()
```

screen2.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MyScreen2(Screen):
    def screen_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen 2')
```

screen2.kv

```
<MyScreen2>:
    name: 'screen_two'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: f'I am {root.name}'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to screen 3'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to next screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to previous screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
        Button:
            text: 'This screen method'
            on_release: root.screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Other screen method (from screen 1)'
            on_release: root.manager.get_screen('screen_one').screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Screen manager method'
            on_release: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
        Button:
            text: 'App method'
            on_release: app.app_method()
```

screen3.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MyScreen3(Screen):
    def screen_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen 3')
```

screen3.kv

```
<MyScreen3>:
    name: 'screen_three'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: f'I am {root.name}'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to screen 1'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen_one'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to next screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to previous screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
        Button:
            text: 'This screen method'
            on_release: root.screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Other screen method (from screen 1)'
            on_release: root.manager.get_screen('screen_one').screen_method()
        Button:
            text: 'Screen manager method'
            on_release: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
        Button:
            text: 'App method'
            on_release: app.app_method()
```

Additionally within `screen1.py` I included how to access same methods which are accessed from kv files but from Python's screen method. As you may notice there is small difference how to access method (or attribute) from kv file and python code, like:

```
kv: root.manager.get_screen('screen_two').screen_method()
python: self.manager.get_screen('screen_two').screen_method()

kv: root.manager.screen_manager_method()
python: self.manager.screen_manager_method()

kv: app.app_method()
python: App.get_running_app().app_method()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem is that there are a thousand possible cases (only kv files, kv + py files, only py with kv inside, with the Builder.load_string method outside or inside the class...). For example I changed the build method of a class inheriting MDApp to the on_enter method inheriting from MDScreen. Already here the first problems arise, because for example the self.theme_cls.primary_palette method doesn't work and if it also inherits from MDApp it gives me an error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind')...

Comment: I agree with you. There is a lot of ways how Kivy apps can be constructed, ways how GUI is created, starting with code based method, kv file as string, as separate kv files, through ways how those files are loaded, what is the root element for GUI: widget like BoxLayout or Screen Manager with screens. You can get lost in it, especially when you trying to learn Kivy based on code snippets from different sources. KivyMD comes with additional level of complexity.

Comment: My tutorial just illustrates one way of creating Kivy app which I personally prefer even for one screen apps. I like the idea of separate code from GUI design. Of course using kv files you can still add or remove widgets using code, which is also great knowing that part of your GUI have to be created dynamically.
In case of how to load kv design I personally do not use Builder methods, knowing that Kivy will load kv with name equal to class name which inherits from App.
If app uses separate kv files I just include them using `#:include` like in my example.